# alternate element in json array angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, sorting

I'm pushing two times different data in my array :

```
$scope.numtickets.push({nbuser:data.users[i].name});
```

so i retrieve data in my view by doing this :

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in numtickets track by $index">
        <li>{{user.nbuser}}</li>
        <li>{{user.nbticket}}</li>
</ul>
```

and few lines after:

```
$scope.numtickets.push({nbticket:data.tickets.length});
```

and this display me this:

[image]

and what i want is to alternate the name and my number.
so i should have : 
Claire pagniez
1
Michel Polnaref
1
Mathilde zimmer
3

and here is what my array display in my console:

[image]

If you see my all code, you can see that i have no choice to push first all names and then all my ticketnumber. So i need to sort elements by alternate name and ticket.
So here is my all code from my controller:

```
$scope.displayuser = function(id) {
  var token = "xxxxxxxx";
  userdisplay
    .send(token, id)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.userbyorga = data.users;
      $scope.numtickets = [];

      for (i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
        var userid = data.users;
        $scope.numtickets.push({
          nbuser: data.users[i].name
        });
        var userarray = JSON.stringify(userid);
        localStorage.setItem("myid", userarray);
      }
    })
    .then(function() {
      var tabuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myid"));
      var urls = [];

      for (i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++) {
        urls.push({
          url: JSON.stringify("https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/" + tabuser[i].id + "/tickets/requested.json")
        });

        displayfilter
          .user(token, tabuser[i].id)
          .then(function(data) {
            $scope.numtickets.push({
              nbticket: data.tickets.length
            });
          });
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you got a good reason not to simply push an item with both properties in your array?

Comment: Yes, it is not the same request i send to the API to retrieve datas

Comment: And can't you wait for the last request to success before you insert the completed object into the array?

Comment: if you show me how, i can do this, because how can i access to my value `data.users[i].name`  at the end of my last request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use user id nested data. at first request create object for each user

```
        for(i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){

            var userid = data.users;
            $scope.numtickets[userid] = {nbuser:data.users[i].name}
            var userarray = JSON.stringify(userid);
            localStorage.setItem("myid",userarray);
        }
```

at second request push **nbticket** by user id

```
       for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++){
            urls.push({
                url:JSON.stringify("https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+tabuser[i].id+"/tickets/requested.json")
            });
            console.log(urls);
            displayfilter
                .user(token,tabuser[i].id)
                .then(function(data){
                    $scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id]['nbticket'] = data.tickets.length
                    console.log($scope.numtickets);

                })
        }
```

you will get object like

```
  {
     1: {
        'nbuser': 'User name1',
        'nbticket': '1',
      },
     2: {
        'nbuser': 'User name2',
        'nbticket': '2',
     }
     3: {
       'nbuser': 'User name3',
       'nbticket': '2',
      }
}
```

Comment: You help me so much ! just one thing, on this line `$scope.numtickets[tabuser[i].id]['nbticket'] = data.tickets.length`, it's saying that " TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined", it can't recognize my array, and i can't manage why can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Only if the number of nbuser is equal to nbtickets & they are in same order try doing this when you push the nbtickets :

`$scope.numtickets.push({nbuser:data.users[i].name});`

then in the second request do this

`for(var i = 0; i < $scope.numtickets.length; i++){
    $scope.numtickets[i].nbticket = data[i].tickets.length;
}`

and then for HTML you can iterate over the $scope.numtickets

`<li ng-repeat="item in numtickets track by $index" ng-click="displayuser(item.id)">
{{item.nbuser}} <br><br>
{{item.name}} <br><br>
</li>`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
cols=_.groupBy(usertab, function(item){ return if(item.nbuser); });
usertab = cols[0];
usernum = cols[1];

<li ng-repeat="item in usertab track by $index" ng-click="displayuser(item.id)">{{item.name}}  {{usernum[$index].name}}</li>
```